# Stop Google App Script from creating duplicate calendar events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

The script below allows me to copy events from one calendar to another using Google App Script and it works great minus the fact I need to run this script say every hour which results in many duplicates being created.

So I was wondering if it is possible to resolve this by adapting the script to somehow check the existing events on the target calendar and only copy new/missing events from the source maybe?

Any help you can provide would be so very much appreciated :)

```
function copyAppointments() {
  const sourceCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxxx@import.calendar.google.com");
  const targetCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxxx@group.calendar.google.com");
  const dt=new Date();
  const starttime  = new Date(dt.getFullYear()-1,dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate(),0,0,0,0);//one year ago
  const endtime = new Date(dt.getFullYear()+1,dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate(),0,0,0,0);//next year
  const events = sourceCalendar.getEvents(starttime,endtime);
  events.forEach(e =>{
    targetCalendar.createAllDayEvent(e.getTitle(),e.getAllDayStartDate(),e.getAllDayEndDate());
  });
}
```

Comment: Run the function from the data of a spreadsheet and put the event id on every event that you create and then you will know that you created it and only create events for lines that don't have event ids

Comment: Depending on how you are running the script, you could use `PropertyService.getScriptProperties()` to store a list of ids as suggested by @Cooper.  Then when you run it again compare the list of events you get from `CalendarApp` and compare with your list from `PropertyService`

Comment: Thank you so so much to both of you for taking the time to respond with your expertise and knowledge. I am a bit of a novice and so really appreciate you pointing me the right direction and providing an example script too. I will now attempt to piece something together haha :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Here is an example of a way to get and store the events that have been processed.  The first time through all events within the time range are stored in Script Properties.  The next time the script is run during the same session no new events have been added.  In your case when this is run periodically and new events are added they will become a list of new events to process and be added to the stored list.

**Script**

```
function runCalendarTest () {
  try {
    let calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxxxxxx@gmail.com");
    let events = calendar.getEvents(new Date(2021,0,1),new Date());
    events = checkIds(events);
    if( events ) {
      console.log(events.length);
    }
    else {
      let service = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
      let ids = service.getProperty("StoredIds");
      console.log(ids)
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in runCalendarTest - "+err);
  }
}

function checkIds(events) {
  try {
    let service = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    let ids = service.getProperty("StoredIds");
    let stored = null;
    if( ids ) {
      ids = ids.split(",");
      events.forEach( event => { let found = ids.find( id => event.getId() === id );
                                 if( !found ) {
                                   stored.push(event);
                                   ids.push(event.getId());
                                 }
                                }
                    );
    }
    else {
      ids = []
      events.forEach( event => ids.push(event.getId()) );
      stored = events;
    }
    ids = ids.join();
    service.setProperty("StoredIds",ids);
    return stored;
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in checkIds - "+err)
  }
}
```

**References**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getAllOwnedCalendars()
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties?hl=en
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service?hl=en#getScriptProperties()